# My Node Js starts and exit automatically when I compile React-native app

Tags: react-native

I have an issue that started to happen few days ago, when I create new project in react native and then trying to start it with "react-native run-android" it starts to compile then shows build successfull but my Node.js not opening it should be started but somehow it is not, how should I fix it ?

I dont see any errors as I mentioned above it shows build successful but node js server wont start

Comment: try to run the "npm start" in the root folder

Comment: It gave me Zone allocation problem,